# How can I enable a server to accept multiple input streams from clients with distinct socket connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to create a simple chat server that allows multiple distinct clients to chat with one another via the server output console. The clients each with their own thread write to the server and can view the results on the server's standard output via the console. However, I can't seem to get the `BufferedReader` to receive the messages coming from more than one client socket connection.

Currently the first client thread gains exclusive access to the `BufferedReader` via it's socket. However, I'd like multiple clients to connect to the server's input stream reader and have it wait for input from multiple client threads with distinct socket connections. I would like clients to be able to post to the server at the same time. How would I accomplish this with or without `BufferedReader` as my input stream reader?

```
public class chatServer {

    public chatServer() throws IOException {

        int PORT = 8189;

        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("The server is running at "
                    + InetAddress.getByName(null) + "...");
            String rules = "The rules of this server are as follows:\n"
                    + "1.Respect your fellow chatters\n"
                    + "2.Vulgar language will result in punishment\n"
                    + "3.We reserve the right to ban you at any time.\n"
                    + "Enjoy!";

            System.out.println(rules + "\n");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    new clientHandler(server.accept()).run();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        chatServer cs = new chatServer();
    }

    class clientHandler implements Runnable {

        Socket socket;

        public clientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while (true) {
                    line = in.readLine();
                    if ((line == null) || line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                        // socket.close();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(socket.getPort() + " > " + line);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

---

```
public class chatClient {

    private Socket socket;
    private String name = "";   
    private String IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private int PORT = 8189;


    public chatClient(String name, String IP, int PORT) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

        this.name = name;
        socket = new Socket(this.IP,this.PORT);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

        chatClient c1 = new chatClient("John",null,0);
        chatClient.connect(c1);

    }

    public static void connect(chatClient cc) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = cc.socket; 
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("Welcome " + cc.name);

        String message = "";
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type your message here:");

        while(!done){
        System.out.print("> ");
        message = stdin.nextLine();
        out.println(message);

        if(message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            done = true;
        }

        }
    }

}
```

**Update:** I'm looking for a suitable/alternative method to achieve the functionality of a Server that accepts multiple posts from various clients with distinct socket connections? If my current implementation cannot do so then how may I modify it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BufferedReader` is constructed around a single reader, which in turn is directly or indirectly connected to a single data source. There is no way of changing that once constructed.

In short your question doesn't make sense. Each client has a distinct socket, which in turn has its unique input and out out streams, which in turn must be wrapped in a distinct `BufferedTeader` per client. Not one shared between all clients.

**EDIT** Your actual problem has nothing to do with `BufferedReaders`. It is here:

```
new clientHandler(server.accept()).run();
```

You're running the handler inline instead of as a separate thread. `run()` should be

```
new Thread(new clientHandler(socket.accept())).start();
```

Comment: What could I use instead of a BufferedReader so that I could share something of the sort between multiple clients. I'm looking for a suitable method to achieve a Server that accepts multiple posts from various clients with distinct socket connections?

Comment: There's nothing here that precludes that. You've just made a bad assumption about how buffered readers work. You need to look at the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: What is the difference between clientHandler extending Thread vs it Implementing Runnable that caused my issue?

What do you mean by "running the handler inline"?

Comment: I didn't say anything about extending Thread vs implementing Runnable. 'Inline' means, err, not as a separate thread.